# Definir qual valor será armazenado em uma variável PHP para ser gravado no Banco

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, sql-server

Eu tenho uma página HTML onde o usuário seleciona as informações que ele precisa e armazena no Banco de Dados quando ele finaliza a operação. É um pequeno formulário em que praticamente só tem caixas de seleção, em exceto uma única caixa de texto.
Em uma das caixas de seleção (tipo problema), quando o usuário clica na opção "Maquinas", aparece outro select, no caso, o de maquinas. E caso o usuário escolha a opção "Outro", então, abrirá a unica caixa de texto da página. Segue a seguir o código atual.

HTML:

```
<select name="tipobroblema" id="tipoproblema">
    <option value="">- Tipo Problema -</option>
    <option value="maquina">Maquina</option>
    <option value="vazamento">Banheiro</option>
    <option value="arcondicionado">Ar Condicionado</option>
    <option value="outro">Outro</option>
</select>

<div id="divOutro" style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="outro" /></div>

<select id="divMaquina" name="maquina" style="display:none;">
    <option value="">- Maquinas -</option>
    <option value="maquina1">Maquinas1</option>
    <option value="maquina2">Maquinas2</option>
    <option value="maquina3">Maquinas3</option>
    <option value="maquina4">Maquinas4</option>
</select>
```

Script:

```
<script>                        
    $('#tipoproblema').change(function(){
    if(this.value == 'maquina') {
        $('#divMaquina').css('display', '');
        $('#divOutro').css('display', 'none');}
    else if(this.value == 'outro') {
        $('#divMaquina').css('display', 'none');
        $('#divOutro').css('display', '');}
    else {
        $('#divMaquina').css('display', 'none');
        $('#divOutro').css('display', 'none');}
   });
</script>
```

Quando o usuário clica em "Gerar" pra gravar no banco, os dados irão pra uma página PHP, assim usando o POST pra pegar os dados que foram informados pelo usuário. Antes de adicionar a caixa de seleção e a de texto "interativas" (que aparecem dependendo da opção selecionada). Eu usava apenas:

```
$problema = $_POST['tipoproblema'];
```

Assim, pegando o valor que o usuário selecionou e passar pra uma variável.

Como era uma só, não havia dificuldade. Ele buscava o nome do campo, no caso "tipoproblema" pegava o valor selecionado e armazenava no Banco de Dados. Agora são três possibilidades. Ou seja, do jeito que estava, ele iria continuar armazenando os tipos de problemas no banco (como o valor "outro" e "maquinas" em vez de gravar a maquina selecionada ou o texto digitado pelo usuário). Não entendo muito de PHP até o momento, agradeceria muito a colaboração de vocês.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você envia o formulário para o `PHP` ele vai criar as chaves do array `$_POST` de acordo com os nomes dos `<input>`s:

```
$tipoproblema=$_POST['tipoproblema'];
$outro=$_POST['outro'];
$maquina=$_POST['maquina'];
```

Assim você consegue capturar os valores dos `<input>`s.

Comment: Sim, eu ja havia feito assim. Mas não sei se dessa forma é viável, pois depois vai complicar pra fazer relatórios..
Eu estava querendo uma solução em que só tivesse um armazenamento. Do qual, um "$tipoproblema=$_POST['tipoproblema'];" já resolvesse. Tudo com apenas uma inserção. Espero que tenha entendido o que eu quis dizer

Comment: Vai complicar fazer relatorio porquê?

Comment: Vc quer salvar todas as informações em um unico campo?

Comment: Eu digo em questão de estética. Muitas vezes vai aparecer dois campos vazios

Comment: só verificar se o campo ta vazio, ele só coloca no relatorio o que tiver preenchido

Comment: Mais ou menos isso. Por exemplo, se o valor "outro" estiver selecionado, então ele vai pegar o valor da caixa de texto e passar pra variável à ser gravada no Banco

Comment: Mas se não tiver preenchido vai salvar vazio do mesmo jeito

Comment: Eu precisava passar pra uma única variável o real problema do usuário. Se o select estiver como "maquina" então vai habilitar o campo de maquinas, o usuário vai selecionar a maquina e só a maquina selecionada será armazenada no Banco. Eu preciso fazer assim porque tenho uma outra pagina pra exibir os problemas, da qual faz um select no banco, puxando o campo "PROBLEMA" talvez teria como concatenar os três campos e formar um valor só, porém, ia ficar uma bagunça, como "Maquinas Maquina XFV23", "Outro Teve um vazamento na pia X do banheiro Y"